# An integration to first order

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

I am having some trouble evaluating an integral -- involving taking an approximation. It would be great if someone could help me.

I wish to evaluate
$$\int_0^\pi {\cos\theta\cos \left[\omega t-{\omega \over c}(a^2+r^2-2rb\cos \theta)^{1\over 2}\right]\over (a^2+r^2-2rb\cos \theta)^{1\over 2}}d\theta$$

for the case where $a\gg r$ and $b=a\sin \phi$, to first order in $1\over a$.

The answer is supposed to be 
$$\pi r^2\omega(\sin \phi)[\sin(\omega t-{\omega\over c}a)]\over 2a$$but I can't see how to get there...

---

There must be some Taylor expansion required. I suppose we could write $$(a^2+r^2-2rb\cos \theta)^{1\over 2}\approx a\left(1-{rb\over a^2}\cos\theta\right)$$

but when next?

---

Ok, if we ignore the given answer -- assuming it is wrong, what should I be getting?

For the argument of the $\cos \left[\omega t-{\omega \over c}(a^2+r^2-2rb\cos \theta)^{1\over 2}\right]$, suppose I Taylor expand $\cos$. It would go something like $$1-{1\over 2}\left[\omega t-{\omega \over c}(a^2+r^2-2rb\cos \theta)^{1\over 2}\right]^2+...$$
However, note that the higher order terms involve terms of $\left(1\over a\right)^n$, with values of $n$ of the non-negligible magnitude. So that can't be the way to do it?

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: You're doing it right. Taylor-expand in $1/a$ and you'll get a simpler integral. Are you having trouble with this step of expansion? Or do you have the integral already and are having trouble evaluating it?

Comment: @Marek: Thank you for replying!! Yes, I am having trouble evaluating that already. There is a $\cos\theta$ in a $\cos$...

Comment: @Marek: I guess I can Taylor expand that outer cos with argument containing the $\cos \theta$. But then every term in the expanded series will contain terms of non-negligible orders in $1\over a$, so it doesn't quite work?

Comment: Well, for integrals like $\cos (A+ B\cos \theta)$ you can try substitutions of the form $x = A + B\cos \theta$. This will also get you rid of the other $\cos \theta$ factors. But looking at the answer you're supposed to obtain again, it seems very weird. First of all, what is $\phi$ doing there? Can you please double-check all the expressions you've entered to make sure we are trying to solve the right problem?

Comment: @Marek:Thanks! Yes, I have checked. It is correct. The $\phi$ comes from $b=a\sin \phi$.

Answer (score 1):

The supposed answer is incorrect. Up to first order, we have $$\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos\theta\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\omega c\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2rb\cos\theta}\right)}{a\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2rb\cos\theta}}\,d\theta\approx\frac{\pi rb\omega\sin(\omega a/c-\omega t)}{2ca^2}.$$

*Proof:* Write $\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2rb\cos\theta}=a\sqrt{1+(r^2-2rb\cos\theta)/a^2}$, which allows us to use $$(1+x)^{\pm1/2}=1\pm\frac{x^2}2+\mathcal O(x^4)$$ for $|x|<1$ (since $a\gg r$). Then\begin{align}I&=\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos\theta\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\omega c\cdot a\sqrt{1+(r^2-2rb\cos\theta)/a^2}\right)}{a\sqrt{1+(r^2-2rb\cos\theta)/a^2}}\,d\theta\\&=\int_0^\pi\left(\frac1a+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{a^3}\right)\right)\cos\theta\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\omega c\left(a+\frac{r^2-2rb\cos\theta}{2a}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{a^3}\right)\right)\right)\,d\theta\\&\approx\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos\theta}a\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\omega c\left(a+\frac{r^2-2rb\cos\theta}{2a}\right)\right)\,d\theta\end{align} up to first order in terms of $1/a$. The cosine addition identity yields \begin{align}I&\approx\small\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos\theta}a\left[\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\omega ca\right)\cos\left(\frac\omega c\frac{r^2-2rb\cos\theta}{2a}\right)+\sin\left(\omega t-\frac\omega ca\right)\sin\left(\frac\omega c\frac{r^2-2rb\cos\theta}{2a}\right)\right]\\&\approx\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos\theta}a\left[\cos\left(\omega t-\frac\omega ca\right)+\sin\left(\omega t-\frac\omega ca\right)\cdot\frac\omega c\frac{r^2-2rb\cos\theta}{2a}\right]\,d\theta\end{align} again up to first order, since $\cos x=1+\mathcal O(x^2)$ and $\sin x=x+\mathcal O(x^3)$. Thus, \begin{align}I&\approx\frac{\omega\sin(\omega t-\omega a/c)}{2ca^2}\int_0^\pi(r^2-2rb\cos\theta)\cos\theta\,d\theta=-\frac{\pi rb\omega\sin(\omega t-\omega a/c)}{2ca^2},\end{align} which [fits reasonably well](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8qtuodu7yw) when $a\gg r$.